# How does ancient Greek polytheism fit with Christianity in The Lusiads?

Tags: cultural-context, religion, portuguese-language, the-lusiads, luis-vaz-de-camoes

*The Lusiads* (*Os Lusíadas*), considered the national epic of Portugal, was written by Luís Vaz de Camões during the 16th century, a period in which the Spanish and Portuguese Inquisitions were menacing the Iberian peninsula and beyond. Some parts of the story (at least in the first two cantos) are almost crusade-like, detailing Vasco da Gama's efforts to promote Christianity over Islam in Africa. On the other hand, several deities of ancient Graeco-Roman polytheism (Bacchus, Venus, Jove) play active roles in the story, reminiscent of Homer's *Iliad* and *Odyssey*.

**How can the appearances of such "pagan" gods be reconciled with Christianity?** I'm interested in both the in-story consistency (how is it possible that da Gama and co are committed Christians but also interact directly with Bacchus?) and the real-world reception (how is it possible that Camões could include Greek gods as characters without falling foul of Christian censors?)

Related previous posts include [this answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/18057/17) and [this answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/18073/17), but I think my question is big enough to be not fully covered by those.